# iOS - Keychain - Lockbox, not saving array on first launch

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am probably doing something wrong, but when I use the code below, and want Lockbox to save elements to the keychain on the first launch of the app nothing is stored. If I then run the app again and add the elements in the else part, then it saves the data.

Any suggestions?

```
NSString *value = @"";
NSArray *array = [Lockbox arrayForKey:@"TestKey"];
value = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];

if(value == nil)
{
    BOOL result = NO;
    NSArray *narray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [value stringByAppendingString:@"key1"],
                       [value stringByAppendingString:@"key2"],
                       [value stringByAppendingString:@"|http://www.url.com/"],
                       [value stringByAppendingString:@"|http://www.url2.com/"],nil];
    result = [Lockbox setArray:narray forKey:@"TestKey"];
}else{
    NSArray *narray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [value stringByAppendingString:@"key1"],
                       [value stringByAppendingString:@"key2"],
                       [value stringByAppendingString:@"|http://www.url.com/"],
                       [value stringByAppendingString:@"|http://www.url2.com/"],nil];
    result = [Lockbox setArray:narray forKey:@"TestKey"];

    NSString *keyv1 =[array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"key value %@",keyv1);

}
```

Comment: where do you have this code?

Comment: I have tried both having it in the AppDelegate in the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and in the viewDidLoad in my settings view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ha! got it .. didnt see it at first:

the first time, nothin is stored in the keychain so array is NIL

value should then be [nil componentsJoinedBy...]

value is nil!

so [nil stringByAppendinString will always be nil and an EMPTY array will be saved on first run

---

on second run array is NOT nil as Lockbox reads back the empty array
(so then all works)

idea, change:

```
NSArray *array = [Lockbox arrayForKey:@"TestKey"];
value = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];

if(value==nil)
...
```

to

```
NSArray *array = [Lockbox arrayForKey:@"TestKey"];
if(array)
     value = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
else
     value = @"";

if(value.length)
...
```

Comment: Changed to this, used value.length == 0 as the test, but still the save is not done until second run. Kinda like it has to store somthing empty first. But I also tried storing somthing empty, and then storing the array after in the first app start, but it does not save until second app start.

Comment: sorry was confused if(array) ... else value = @"" | edited my answer

Comment: the point is value is nil when you try to append to it... msgs to nil result in nil